# Full text search not working properly

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

If I type a description like `8in Wrench`, I expect to get back a result like `WRENCH ADJUSTABLE CRESCENT 8IN` but instead I get no results found. If I search `Adjustable Wrench` or `Crescent Wrench` it works fine but not for `8in wrench`.

Why aren't the desired results being returned?

Here is the mysql query

```
$term = request()->term;
$exp = explode(' ', $term);

$s = '';
$c = 1;
foreach ($exp AS $e)
{
    $s .= "+$e*";

    if ($c + 1 == count($exp))
        $s .= ' ';

    $c++;
}


SELECT
   `items`.`*`,
   `itemunits`.`*`,
   `vendoritems`.`*`,
FROM
   `items` 
   INNER JOIN
      `itemunits` 
      ON `itemunits`.`itemcode` = `items`.`itemcode` 
   INNER JOIN
      `vendoritems` 
      ON `vendoritems`.`itemcode` = `items`.`itemcode` 
WHERE
   (
      `items`.`deleted` = 0 
      AND `vendoritems`.`deleted` = 0 
   )
   AND 
   (
      MATCH (items.description) AGAINST ( $s IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
      OR MATCH (vendoritems.partnumber) AGAINST ('$s' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   )
GROUP BY
   `items`.`itemcode`,
   `vendoritems`.`itemcode`,
   `itemunits`.`itemcode` 
ORDER BY
   items.description"
```

Comment: You might be searching for a word shorter than `innodb_ft_min_token_size`, which defaults to 4. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: I just checked and its set to 4 so that might indeed be the issue